# Getting empty response from Titanium getResponseData() where there should be data

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I'm trying to get a response from a third party server. If I try to get the response from postman. I get an array of objects. So it does work, I'm pretty sure it does actually. However when I try to do it on my app it returns this empty array:

LOG:

```
[INFO] :   SUCCESS AddressAddressListGet
[INFO] :   Status code 200
[INFO] :   DATA response: []
[INFO] :   Text response: []
[INFO] :   Todos os HEADERS Transfer-Encoding:Identity
[INFO] :   Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
[INFO] :   Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
[INFO] :   Date:Wed, 28 Mar 2018 20:36:49 GMT
[INFO] :   Connected? false
[INFO] :   Type of connection GET
```

Here's the actual CODE:

```
var httpRequest = function(url, timeout, _headers, method, _data, onSuc, onErr) 
{
   var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
     onload: onSuc,
     onerror: onErr,
     timeout: timeout //5000
   });


  client.open(method, url);
  if (_headers.length != 0 && _headers != 0){
     for (var key in _headers) {
       client.setRequestHeader(key, _headers[key]);
        if (_data.length != 0 && _data != 0)
        {
          client.send(JSON.stringify(_data));
        } else {
          client.send();
   }
}; //END OF FUNC HTTPREQUEST()


var AddressAddressListGet = function(onSuc, onErr, accountId) {
   if(typeof(accountId) == 'undefined' || accountId == 0)
   {
        var url = urlAddressAddressListGet + "?accountId=" + accountId;
   }
   else {
       var url = urlAddressAddressListGet;
   }
   var header = {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "Authorization": Ti.App.TOKEN
   };
   var _data = 0;
   httpRequest(url, TIMEOUT, header, "GET", _data, onSuc, onErr);
}; //AddressAddressListGet
```

Here's my on success callback function:

```
var onsucAddressAddressListGet = function(e) {
  console.log('SUCCESS AddressAddressListGet');
  console.log("Status code " + this.getStatus());
  console.log("DATA response: " + this.getResponseData());
  console.log("Text response: " + this.getResponseText());
  console.log("Todos os HEADERS " + this.getAllResponseHeaders());
  console.log("Connected? " + this.getConnected());
  console.log("Type of connection " + this.getConnectionType());
};
```

Any help or ideas on how to solve this problem would be of great help :D

Comment: Can you show an example of the raw response from Postman?

Comment: Does `this.responseText;` contain anything?

Comment: Sorry, guys! The third party guys pointed us to a slightly different URI!
They have a bunch of testing servers. And everything went wrong because of an Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key, used upon calling the methods. They guaranteed that keeping it on the header would not interfere since we were by-passing the server authentication. Thank you for your help.